# "The app has not been released on AppGallery" error on InAppComment Huawei request

Tags: flutter, huawei-mobile-services

I have it published in AppGallery with open testing and a configured pushkit.

However, when trying to evaluate the application, the screen triggers, and there is an error:

> The app has not been released on AppGallery

- Physical Device: Realme RMX3263
- AppGallery: 13.5.2.300
- HMS Core:6.13.0.302
- SignIn in AppGallery: yes

Checked all the conditions from the package [in_app_comments](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_comments):

> - You have released your app officially on AppGallery.
> - Users have installed AppGallery `11.3.2.302` or later and signed in using HUAWEI IDs.
> - Testing the Function
> - If your app has been released on AppGallery, you need to release an open testing version for it and then perform the testing.
> - If your app has not been released on AppGallery, you need to release an open testing version for it and then perform the testing. Otherwise, app authentication will fail.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Hey mate i believe you need an actual Huawei devices in order for the package to work.
You can see the ReadMe on the package specifically told you `It only works on Huawei phones and uses the In-App Comments API`

Just try to find the Huawei device and test if you still get the error

Cheers

Comment: There is some truth in this

Comment: DId you test on Huawei device??